# How to return index of element using Protractor filter with ng-repeater

Tags: protractor

I want to get an ng-repeater element by its aria-label but want to click on corresponding different tag for this repeater element. How can I do that using filter.

```
Web Page: 
<workspace-group-handler ng-if="!inputCache.search" ng-repeat="group in groups" group="group" class=""><!---->

 <!----><workspace-tile tabindex="0" aria-label="Test" edit-mode="$ctrl.editMode" workspace="$ctrl.group" ng-if="$ctrl.group.type === 'workspace' &amp;&amp; 


<div class="tile" ng-class="{'selected-tile': isSelected}" ng-click="openWorkspace($ctrl.workspace); $ctrl.toggleSelected($ctrl.workspace)" ng-right-click="toggleDropdown($event)" aria-haspopup="true" dnd-draggable="$ctrl.workspace" dnd-dragstart="$ctrl.notifyDragstart()" dnd-dragend="$ctrl.notifyDragend()" role="button" tabindex="0" draggable="true">

   <div class="ws-icon">
```

I am trying following:

```
 this.AllWorkspace = element.all(by.repeater('group in groups'));
 this.WSLabel = this.AllWorkspace.all(by.css('workspace-tile'));
 this.WSIcon = this.AllWorkspace.all(by.css('div .ws-icon'));

 WSLabel.filter(function(elem, index) {
    return elem.getAttribute("aria-label").then(function(text) {
        return text.toUppercase() === 'TEST', index; //want to return index and element both not sure how to do this
      });
    }).then(function(filteredElements, index) {
        console.log("Workspace Name found click on it");
      this.WSIcon.get(index).click();
    });
```

How can I return the index of elements using filter? Based on text match I want to get the index of this element and want to use same index to click on another element.

Comment: There needs to be a space in the css selector -- 'div .ws-icon'. Instead of then and the index you can use .first().element.....

Comment: sorry for the typo in my code but this is not the actual problem I am trying to solve, I have modify my question please go throw it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could add each element details into an object and push the object into an array. Should be possible using the each method of element.all()

```
var details = [];

WSLabel.each(function (elem,index) {
    elem.getText().then(function (text) {
         if (text === 'TEST') {
             var obj = {};

             obj.text = text;
             obj.element = elem;
             obj.index = index;

             details.push(obj);
         }
     });
});
```